# How to submit jqxdatetimeinput value to server via a POST on a ASP .net page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqwidget

I want to pick up the value of a jqxdatetimeinput when a button is clicked on the form to generate a postback. The jqxdatetimeinput has text input but it is not named so it does show as up a parameter of the form. Should I be sending the value back to the server some other way? I thought of using an event to sync the value of the jqxdatetimeinput to another hidden input field from which I can get the value on the server side but it seems a bit clunky.